# bootstrap modal only working once when I have the word fade

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I'm using bootstrap modals, and showing and hiding them from javascript like this:

```js
    $("#download_polling_box").modal("show")
    ...
    $("#download_polling_box").modal("hide")
```

however - when I had the following:

```html
<div class="modal fade">
```

It worked great... once...   From then on - show worked, but hide just... didn't.  You could still hit close on the dialog, and it would go away but hide from javascript wouldn't work.

I did lots of googling and found a stack overflow that said just remove "fade". So I did... and it fixed the problem perfectly.

But...  I want the fade effect.  Is it possible to have both?

Comment: You can show and hide a modal with `fade` as many times as you want.  If it isn't working for you, there's a problem in your code, and you'll need to show us a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for anyone to be able to help.

Comment: create a snippet with your code

Comment: There is not enough here to see the problem, and without more info/code, nobody can help. Please edit your question and add details - until then, I'm voting to close as "*Needs debugging details*".